# Problems with UPDATE MySQL inPython

Tags: python, mysql

I have a simple problem when I update a MySQL table. I want to change the columns REMOVED in my table where there is a matching ID. I'm using the code below:

```
c = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    sql = "UPDATE `bas` SET removed = %s WHERE id = &s"
    print(row)
    print(sql)
    c.execute(str(sql), tuple(row))
    
    mydb.commit()
```

This code returns the following: ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Is there an obvious problem with the sql query?

Comment: can you post the full code ?

Comment: Also this like looks error : "UPDATE `bas` SET removed = %s WHERE id = &s"
&s must be replaced with %s & where are the string formatted values ?

Comment: To be more specific, you have `&s` at the end when it should be `%s`. Voting to close as caused by a typo.

Comment: Correct way to string format is something like this as example : "UPDATE `bas` SET removed = %s WHERE id = %s" % ('a', 'b')

Comment: @ShekharSamanta: that's not correct for database queries. The way Henrik is doing it is good, except for the typo.

Comment: @mechanical_meat he mentioned WHERE id = %s so what value will be there in place of %s in the query ?

Comment: @ShekharSamanta The second element of `tuple(row)`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar
last line mydb.commit() must be c.commit() ?

Comment: @ShekharSamanta No. You execute with cursor, but commit on the DB.

Comment: Thanks @Barnar! Got it. executing with cursor & committing with connection.

Comment: Just a typo! I did not see that! Thanks!

Comment: This solution is very slow thou. :) But that is another topic of course.